# What information can you extract from a spatial Fourier transform of the electric field?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform

Suppose we had a 2D grid of electric field points of some generated radiation field (synchrotron radiation, for example). At some instant of time, the radiation field will be finite in space. What information can we extract from the system from the spatial ($\vec{r}$ and $\vec{k}$) Fourier transform at this particular instance in time?

Comment: Do you mean that you have all the Fourier components of the field at some given instance of time? Then you can get the field at this instance of time itself via the inverse Fourier transform, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such spatial Fourier transforms are commonly used in optics, both in theoretical treatments and in image analysis. An optical field is, of course, an example of an electromagnetic field. The main difference is that much of optics is done in the *scalar approximation* where one ignores the vector nature of the field. But you can also Fourier analyse vector fields of course.

As a mathematical method, the Fourier analysis is useful because you can solve the wave equation that way. Each plane wave component propagates in a simple way. This is a good way to formulate studies of diffraction, for example. It is also a good way to understand the resolving power of an instrument such as a microscope. In these treatments the components at the various $\bf k$ are said to be the various *spatial frequencies* in the field. Higher spatial frequencies correspond to finer detail in an image such as the one formed by a microscope.

The same terminology may be used in image analysis and manipulation. For example, one can sharpen an image by removing the low spatial frequencies, and one can blur an image be removing the high spatial frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Use spherical coordinates $(R,\theta, \phi)$; in the Fraunhofer far-field zone ($R \to \infty$) the field, say $\mathcal {E}(\theta, \phi)$, can be written as a 2D Fourier transform of the source distribution $F(\xi, \eta)$ here assumed to be planar whose rectangular coordinates are $(\xi, \eta)$: $$ \mathcal {E}(\theta, \phi) \approx \frac {\mathfrak{j}}{2\lambda} \frac {e^ {-\mathfrak{j}kR}}{R} \int_{source} F(\xi, \eta) e^{\mathfrak{j}ksin\theta(\xi cos\phi+\eta sin\phi)} d\xi d\eta$$ 
If you know $\mathcal {E}(\theta, \phi)$ this FT can be inverted to get the source distribution $F(\xi, \eta)$. If you have a discretized set of points, grid, where you measured the field then you will have to perform an inverse DFT. Note that the inversion is sensitive to noise, sampling density, and tapering ("Gibbs phenomenon").